# Find Class name then remove id #

Tags: jquery, attr

Hi I am trying to remove all id from a div with a common class name:

```
$('div.panel-group').removeAttr('id', '');
```

But does not work. I do not want (e.g find id then remove id) as there a stacks of generated ID's

Thx

Comment: try with only 1 parameter: `.removeAttr('id')` | https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Comment: `$('div.panel-group').removeAttr('id');` if you have 2 parameter you are just setting

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I can successfully do $('#myID123').removeAttr('id'); but I want to search upon class name.

Comment: @RRowan you need specify which element you want to remove the ID from using index of a more specific selector

Comment: @RRowan can you provide html so we can have a firm grasp on what is problem on hand

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me, I display an alert with the ID of the element and I delete the ID of the element, then if I display again an alert the ID is undefined.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="test">
First Div
</div>
<div class="panel-group" id="test2">
Second Div
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('div.panel-group').each(function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
      $(this).removeAttr('id');
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Also check the Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f72q9wao/

Anyways, try to share some HTML so we can have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this. this will explain what you want. 
try click on the first div, if the class name equals to your finding name , it will remove the id of the the div.then it will remove all the styles, for that id.try it. hope this will help to you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">
div.container div{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border:1px solid black;
 margin:20px;
 cursor: pointer;

}

.first{
 background-color: orange;
}

.second{
 background-color: pink;
}

.third{
 background-color: purple;
}

#firstid{
 border:10px solid red;
}

</style>

<body>
 
<div class="container">
 <div class="first" id="firstid">class = "first" and <br> id="firstid"</div>
 <div class="first" id="secondid">class = "first" and <br>id="secondid"</div>
 <div class="second" id="thirdid">class = "second" and <br>id="thirdid"</div>
 <div class="third" id="fourthid">class = "third" and <br>id="fourthid"</div>
</div>


</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
  $("div.container div").click(function(){
   var the_class = $(this).attr('class');//get the class name of clicked one
   var the_id = $(this).attr('id');//get the id of the clicked

   alert("The class name :"  +the_class + " and the id :"+the_id);

   //then implment your condition
   if (the_class == "first") 
   {
    $("[class='first']").removeAttr('id');
   }



  });
  
 });


</script>
</html>
```